# Reghdfe for stacked regression in Stata

Tags: r, stata, difference, fixed, effect

I am trying to run a difference in difference regression on a stacked data set.
The stacking refers to the fact that a treatment company is always paired with a control company. These pairs are then stacked vertically.
The data takes the following general specification as seen in the picture.

[image: Data Set Up]

In total there are 50 pairs. There are also other control variables next to the outcome.

The regression specification I aim to run is the following:
[image: Regression spec]
Here T indicates that unit s is treated in pair d, and P indicates that period t is post treatment in in pair d. What this achieves is that time and unit fixed effects are also combined with a pair identifier.

I am unsure how to set this up correctly in Stata with `reghdfe` or in R, or how to specify the multilevel fixed effects the interaction term here.

I've tried using `reghdfe` in Stata by including an interaction between my pair ID and unit identifiers in the fixed effects, as well as interacting pair ID with the date, but seem to face problems with the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code did you try? What specific problems?

Comment: I tried reghdfe outcome particpate treatment participate##treatment control1 control2, absorb (pairID##CompanyName pairID##Date) cluster (CompanyName)

Comment: That should help anyone who uses this command (not me) -- but such people also need to know what problems you ran into.

Comment: You are unlikely to get help with R code unless you show some attempt at such.